# H2 Mem & Geometry Data with Spring Boot 3.2

Tags: spring-boot, gis, h2

**Context**

I have a application that uses `POINT` data for latitude and longitude in my database in Spring Boot 3.2. The production database is MySQL and I can insert the point data with statements like:

```
ST_PointFromText('POINT(-36.5 174.5)', 4326)
```

But for developement I am using H2 in-memory database. How can I insert latitude longitude data into the H2 database. I am using Hibernate Geolatte dependency.

**Build.gradle**

```
implementation group: 'org.geolatte', name: 'geolatte-geom', version: '1.9.0'
implementation group: 'org.geolatte', name: 'geolatte-geojson', version: '1.9.0'
implementation group: 'org.hibernate.orm', name: 'hibernate-spatial', version: '6.2.6.Final'
implementation group: 'org.orbisgis', name: 'h2gis', version: '2.2.0'
runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
```

**Entity**

```
import org.geolatte.geom.G2D;
import org.geolatte.geom.Point;

@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "test_check")
public class TestCheck {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private Point<G2D> location;
```

When I try to run the same data.sql that I use for MySQL I am getting errors related to the insertion of the geometry.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to ensure that you reference the call to load [`H2GIS_SPATIAL`](https://cookieandkate.com/huevos-rancheros-recipe/) first in data.sql.

```
CREATE ALIAS IF NOT EXISTS H2GIS_SPATIAL FOR "org.h2gis.functions.factory.H2GISFunctions.load";
CALL H2GIS_SPATIAL();
```

Then change from `ST_PointFromText('POINT(-36.5 174.5)', 4326)` to using the H2 syntax of the same statement `ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-32.5, 174.5), 4326))`

H2 seems to store the points in a Text based format instead of binary - perhaps someone know more on why this is.

Comment: H2 has own `GEOMETRY` data type with binary encoding and H2GIS extension has `ST_PointFromText` function.